# Java 11 compiler returns "package does not exist"

Tags: java, package, structure

I am trying to re-learn some programming skills.

I have decided to use an old favourite - Logic Gates Simulation - as a learning tool.

I want to set this project up to use packages.

My CLASSPATH is "C:\Users\ruthm\Documents\java"

My project code is in the directory:

C:\Users\ruthm\Documents\java\logic

I am using Java 11

My classes so far are Connector.java and ConnectorTest.java

the code for Connector is as follows:

```
package logic;

/* 
Class Connector

A connector forms the input and output of a LogicGate.
The connector "output" object of a gate can be passed to another gate to form the input.


*/


public class Connector{
    private int value;
    
    public Connector(){
        value=0;
    }
    public Connector(int state){
        value=state;
    }
    public void setValue(int state){
        value=state;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

The code for Connector Test is as follows:

```
/* Test Case for Connector */

import logic.*;


class ConnectorTest{
        public static void main (String[] args){
            logic.Connector myConnector = new logic.Connector();
            System.out.println("initial value: "+myConnector.getValue());
            myConnector.setValue(1);
            System.out.println("Set value: "+myConnector.getValue());
        }
}
```

Connector.java compiles without error.
When I try to compile ConnectorTest.java I get the following from the compiler:

```
C:\Users\ruthm\Documents\java\logic>javac ConnectorTest.java
ConnectorTest.java:4: error: package logic does not exist
import logic.*;
^
ConnectorTest.java:9: error: package logic does not exist
                        logic.Connector myConnector = new logic.Connector();
                             ^
ConnectorTest.java:9: error: package logic does not exist
                        logic.Connector myConnector = new logic.Connector();
                                                               ^
3 errors

C:\Users\ruthm\Documents\java\logic>
```

I have been following guides on directory structure and packages to try and solve this but I am clearly not understanding something.

I get the same errors if I declare ConnectorTest to be in package logic as well.

Can someone handhold me and show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: If `Connector` and `ConnectorTest` are in the same directory it would be easier to also have them in the same package. As it is written I would expect `ConnectorTest` to be inside `C:\Users\ruthm\Documents\java` instead. Or somewhere else, at which point you need to tell your compiler where to find the `logic` package.

Comment: Is the title better now?

Comment: I forgot to mention, if they're in the same package, you don't need to import `logic`. And in any case, if  you *do* import `logic` then you don't need to call the class by its fully qualified name. `import`s are meant exactly to avoid that.

Comment: The issue has been that ConnectorTest.java was in the same directory as Connector.java

It would seem that the packages assume that the current directory is the top of the package.  I understand a little more now.  I think I need to rearrange my directory structure a little as I wanted "java" to be the main directory for all future projects.

Thank you all for your comments.  I am away now until after work.  If this question should be closed now then I will do it when I get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My project code is in the directory:
>
> C:\Users\ruthm\Documents\java\logic

This means that to avoid trouble, you'd be better off using same package directive to them both.

So if you add this:

```
package logic;
```

to your ConnectorTest class, it should be ok, given you don't have any other issues.

If you want to keep your ConnectorTest class in default package, you could move your ConnectorTest.java file to C:\Users\ruthm\Documents\java directory, but keep your Connector class in the logic directory.

Comment: that's exactly what worked for me.  I couldn't get the test class to compile when using "package logic" but I do understand a bit more now.